# How would you implement a Newsletter form in Ember?

Tags: forms, security, ember.js, tastypie, newsletter

I'm new in Ember and right now I'm developping a website that uses Django+TastyPie+Ember. It wasn't until receantly that I had to deal with data getting back to the server, and I feel that I still don't see the full picture here.

Without having user accounts yet, I was wondering what was the "recommended" way of implement a form to to register to a newsletter, where someone introduces their email and it's saved, for instance, into the database.

Comment: Check out Ember-data.

Comment: Hi, I've been checking out Ember-data and it seems ok, but is the security issue that concerns me. I'm using an API to talk to the server so I will need to have a API resource open to which users can post data right? Could I implement a CSRF Protection mechanism on Ember? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm kind of new in this domain :P